# How to sort php array by value and add an array to another

Tags: php, arrays, steam-web-api

Okay, so I'm writing an app that allows me to see steam data from a database of whoever registered.

I met a problem. Firstly, the steam API for multiple users is not standardized. (e.g. everytime you refresh [this](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=0E8371DA5BAFD664F417DFA05E9B843F&steamids=76561198025035234,76561197968270056,76561197982490298&format=json), the position of user changes (What kind of API does this?!)

Since steam does not standardize the API, I'll have to do it myself, so after doing a json_decode($url, true). It is not an assoc array.

I want to sort the assoc array by the steam ID (which is numeral) and match them against my own database of user (also contains steam ID, but can be sorted in the database), so how do I go about doing that?

E.g.

Array 1:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["steam_id32"]=>
    string(17) "76561198025035234"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Mitsuki"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["steam_id32"]=>
    string(17) "76561197968270056"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "nrn"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["steam_id32"]=>
    string(17) "76561197982490298"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Ximp"
  }
}
```

Array 2:

```
array(1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["players"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(16) {
        ["steamid"]=>
        string(17) "76561197982490298"
        ["communityvisibilitystate"]=>
        int(3)
        ["profilestate"]=>
        int(1)
        ["personaname"]=>
        string(53) "Â…Â…â€®â€®â€®â€®â€®â€®â€®â€®â€®â€®Ximp Â…Â…FUS RO DAH"
        ["lastlogoff"]=>
        int(1328569605)
        ["profileurl"]=>
        string(34) "http://steamcommunity.com/id/ximp/"
        ["avatar"]=>
        string(114) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f8/f8ee0cf00a2ec20417bf5b26b99fd6fb4dc176c1.jpg"
        ["avatarmedium"]=>
        string(121) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f8/f8ee0cf00a2ec20417bf5b26b99fd6fb4dc176c1_medium.jpg"
        ["avatarfull"]=>
        string(119) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f8/f8ee0cf00a2ec20417bf5b26b99fd6fb4dc176c1_full.jpg"
        ["personastate"]=>
        int(1)
        ["realname"]=>
        string(9) "I life in"
        ["primaryclanid"]=>
        string(18) "103582791430354400"
        ["timecreated"]=>
        int(1146939839)
        ["gameextrainfo"]=>
        string(20) "The Binding Of Isaac"
        ["gameid"]=>
        string(6) "113200"
        ["loccountrycode"]=>
        string(2) "DE"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(14) {
        ["steamid"]=>
        string(17) "76561197968270056"
        ["communityvisibilitystate"]=>
        int(3)
        ["profilestate"]=>
        int(1)
        ["personaname"]=>
        string(3) "nrn"
        ["lastlogoff"]=>
        int(1328618220)
        ["profileurl"]=>
        string(34) "http://steamcommunity.com/id/nrnx/"
        ["avatar"]=>
        string(114) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/50/50b908e0aa2c730fa0f68ab0afc8b04fddb133f1.jpg"
        ["avatarmedium"]=>
        string(121) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/50/50b908e0aa2c730fa0f68ab0afc8b04fddb133f1_medium.jpg"
        ["avatarfull"]=>
        string(119) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/50/50b908e0aa2c730fa0f68ab0afc8b04fddb133f1_full.jpg"
        ["personastate"]=>
        int(1)
        ["realname"]=>
        string(9) "Nathaniel"
        ["primaryclanid"]=>
        string(18) "103582791432850562"
        ["timecreated"]=>
        int(1092771678)
        ["loccountrycode"]=>
        string(2) "US"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(14) {
        ["steamid"]=>
        string(17) "76561198025035234"
        ["communityvisibilitystate"]=>
        int(3)
        ["profilestate"]=>
        int(1)
        ["personaname"]=>
        string(23) "[ProudiA] Mitsuki Sakai"
        ["lastlogoff"]=>
        int(1328621807)
        ["commentpermission"]=>
        int(1)
        ["profileurl"]=>
        string(42) "http://steamcommunity.com/id/mitsukisakai/"
        ["avatar"]=>
        string(114) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9d/9d279f349422cbbed55adf1c8eabb0924ea0a719.jpg"
        ["avatarmedium"]=>
        string(121) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9d/9d279f349422cbbed55adf1c8eabb0924ea0a719_medium.jpg"
        ["avatarfull"]=>
        string(119) "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9d/9d279f349422cbbed55adf1c8eabb0924ea0a719_full.jpg"
        ["personastate"]=>
        int(1)
        ["realname"]=>
        string(12) "é…’äº•å‚è¼"
        ["primaryclanid"]=>
        string(18) "103582791432752089"
        ["timecreated"]=>
        int(1273714689)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "(What kind of API does this?!)" -- you're getting back an object, not an array. Objects in JSON are not inherently ordered.

Comment: Ah I see, but shouldn't it at least be in order of how I called the API?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve: if you just want to compare/match the entries against the data in your DB - do it using the IDs - why does the order matter ?
If it's for display purposes (and then the order is indeed important) - you can save the IDs into a data structure while you preform the matching/comparing of the info against your DB - then select all the relevant entries from your DB (with the saved IDs) and use "order by".

Answer (score -1):

For sortig array you can find a list of all function that you need [here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

**Update:**

first you must create a `1d` array from a `2d` or `3d` you can use this code to make an easy access array and sortable (this an example):

```
<?php
$inArr;//This is the 2D array
$outArr = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($inArr);$i++){
   $outArr[$i] = $inArr[$i][0];
?>
```

then you can sort it with `ksort()` or `krsort()` function.and for adding an array to another :

```
<?php
  $stack = array("value1", "value2");
  array_push($stack, "value3", "value4");
  print_r($stack);
?>
```

Comment: He wants to sort the array by a key that is in an array in the element.  This doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: @thenetimp first read the http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php exactly then give -1.pay more attention please

Comment: @thenetimp for example : `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php` or `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php`

Comment: Hi bizzare, I read through the array.sorting, but I ended up having a headache, could you please point me to which sorting I should use? Thanks!

Comment: @Omfgitsasalmon krsort() or ksort()

Comment: @bizzare your code that you included did not even mention how to sort.  You only linked to the array documentation didn't even mention the function he had to use until he asked for it. so Yes you get a -1 If he changes it and gives you a check then you get it back.

Comment: -1 here too, you're just pasting examples from the docs instead of helping him with his issue. Put some effort into responses. I don't see any oranges or bananas in his data.

Comment: @Interrobang ok updated.but i thinks its not very important , my answer give him a direction to a true solution.totally thanks for your attention